# PHP Multidimensional Arrays - Adding additional records in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate a multidimensional array while looping through a regular array, but I am finding my code is overwriting each record as opposed to adding a new key. here is a condensed version of what i am working on - $AdjustePerWeekSorted is the regular array

```
$CSVKey = 0;
foreach ($AdjustedPerWeekSorted as $item) {
$data = array (
            $CSVKey => 
                array (
                'Overall Rank' => (array_search($item,$AllAdjustedPerWeekSorted) + 1),
                'Name' => $AdjustedNames[array_search($item,$AdjustedPerWeek)],
                'Adjusted Positional Score' => $item,
                'Position' => $AdjustedPOS[array_search($item,$AdjustedPerWeek)]
                ),      
            );
        $CSVKey = $CSVKey + 1;              
}
```

my thought process is this:
for $AdjustedPerWeekSorted[0] -> populate $data[$CSVKey] = MultiDarray 
   add 1 to $CSVKey
   loop to next record

for $AdjustedPerWeekSorted[1] -> populate $data[$CSVKey + 1] = MultiDarray and so on...

all of my post processing of this is working fine, however I am only populating the $data array with the LAST record's data in the $AdjustedPerWeekSorted array. Anybody willing to point me in the correct direction? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simplify this with `$CSVKey++;` and `$data[$CSVKey] =`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will build an array using `$CSVKey` as the index instead of overwriting:

```
$data[$CSVKey] = array (
                'Overall Rank' => (array_search($item,$AllAdjustedPerWeekSorted) + 1),
                'Name' => $AdjustedNames[array_search($item,$AdjustedPerWeek)],
                'Adjusted Positional Score' => $item,
                'Position' => $AdjustedPOS[array_search($item,$AdjustedPerWeek)]
                );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel like a bit of a dummy looking at how you did this - definitely should have been able to do this on my own but it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You coud simple do it this way:

```
<?php


$data = array();    
foreach ($AdjustedPerWeekSorted as $item) {
    $data[]
        = array(
        'Overall Rank'              => (array_search(
                $item,
                $AllAdjustedPerWeekSorted
            ) + 1),
        'Name'                      => $AdjustedNames[array_search(
            $item,
            $AdjustedPerWeek
        )],
        'Adjusted Positional Score' => $item,
        'Position'                  => $AdjustedPOS[array_search(
            $item,
            $AdjustedPerWeek
        )]

    );

}
```

If you create Integer keys array and starts from 0 there's no need to use `$CSVKey`